# How to access a specific element of a DataFrame in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

With a NumericMatrix, it is easy to access a specific element. For example, we can access the element of row i and col j of the NumericMatrix X with X(i, j). Is there an equivalent operator for a Rcpp::DataFrame?

I am looking for a yes/no answer or a short example.

Comment: https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/140_dataframe.html#accessing-dataframe-elements says that the path is to access a column as a vector, at which point individual elements can be access. Is there a convenient `(i,j)`? I don't know that there is, but creating a vector for your column and then indexing it seems straightforward (if not "just one" expression).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is straightforward, but I am not sure is it very efficient if have to access a large number of values. For example, for a particular problem, I have a data.frame with 35 000 rows and 150 000 columns and I have to access a large number of values. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a yes/no answer or a short example.

The short answer is a no, just as to your question from yesterday. A `data.frame` is a list of vectors so a *homogenous*-style accessor cannot work as it does for a Matrix.

A short example of *what actually works* follows. Note that this appears to have been answered by the [DataFrame example](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/DataFrameExample.cpp) in package [RcppExamples](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples) from which can quote:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List DataFrameExample(const DataFrame & DF) {

    // access each column by name
    IntegerVector a = DF["a"];
    CharacterVector b = DF["b"];
    DateVector c = DF["c"];
    
    // do something
    a[2] = 42;
    b[1] = "foo";
    c[0] = c[0] + 7; // move up a week
    
    // create a new data frame
    DataFrame NDF = DataFrame::create(Named("a")=a,
                                      Named("b")=b,
                                      Named("c")=c);
    
    // and return old and new in list
    return List::create(Named("origDataFrame") = DF,
                        Named("newDataFrame") = NDF);
}
```

It helps to rember that a `data.frame` really *is* a list of vectors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, I am looking for an operator based on the row index or the column index of a data.frame. In my code Rcpp code, I have a Rcpp::DataFrame with an unknown size and I want to be able to access a specific element at row i and column j efficiently. I searched and found your answer in a post, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: There is none as best as I can tell, and my comment ("list of vectors") gives a hint as to why.  In short, "wishing alone does not make it so" but all these packages are extensible: maybe you find a way the Rcpp authors didn't?  They may take a patch.

Comment: @EmmanuelHamel Looking at your profile it seems you never accepted an answer to any of the questions you asked. That is ... a bit unusual and likely not a great way to motivate others to help you.